Proving equality of two polynomials over finite field
Let $\mathbb F$ be a finite field with $q$ elements and let $f,g\in\mathbb F[x]$. Note that $F(x)=f(x+\frac{1}{x})$ and $G(x)=g(x+\frac{1}{x})$ are elements of the field of rational expressions $\mathbb F(x)$.
My Question: Is it true that if $F=G$ in $\mathbb F(x)$, then $f=g$ in $\mathbb F[x]$ ?
My attempt Let $\mathbb K$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F$. Hence, for every $x\in\mathbb F$, there exists $z\in\mathbb K$ such that $x=z+1/z$. Hence, as rational functions $f(z)=g(z)$ for every $z\in\mathbb K$. My problem is that we can not deduce that $f=g$, since the field is finite.

Yes, this is true over any base field $F$, finite or infinite. Your argument is not hard to salvage (but you switch the roles of $x$ and $z$ midway which is confusing):
Over the algebraic closure $\overline{F}$ it's in fact the case that for any $z \in \overline{F}$ (not just in $F$), there exists $x \in \overline{F}$ such that $z = x + \frac{1}{x}$. It follows that $f(z) = g(z)$ for every $z \in \overline{F}$ (this line of your argument is true but it doesn't follow from the previous line), and since $\overline{F}$ is infinite (even if $F$ is finite) it follows that $f = g$ identically.
There is also a simpler and more direct argument. Namely, the leading coefficient of $F$ is the same as the leading coefficient of $f$ (just expand it out), so if $F = G$ then the leading coefficients of $f$ and $g$ agree. Now subtract these off and compare the remaining coefficients. By induction on the degree we get $f = g$.
However, the first argument above generalizes to the case that $x + \frac{1}{x}$ is replaced by any non-constant rational function, and $f$ and $g$ can also be rational rather than just polynomial.

Thanks @Qiaochu Yuan for your answer. Regarding the second method you mentioned: what do you mean by "leading coefficient"? $F$ is a rational expression, not a polynomial.

@boaz: $F$ is a Laurent polynomial, so it can be written $F(x) = \sum F_n x^n$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. By leading coefficient I mean the nonzero coefficient with largest $n$.

The sum $F(x)$ is finite since the expression $x+\frac{1}{x}$ is plugged into $f$, right?

Yes, it's a finite sum.
